# asp:chart is not available on visual web developer 2008 express edition

Tags: asp.net, charts

I just installed microsoft chart controls software on my system. Now the chart is present on the data toolbox on visual C# 2008 express edition. But it is not available on visual web developer 2008 express edition

When I tried

`<asp:chart >`

it is not available...

Do I have to do some procedure to get it active on web developer.

Can anyone tell me what is the problem...

---

I added the below said to the web.config, The  is available but I am getting an error..

```
The type or namespace name 'DataVisualization' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Web.UI' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
```

What should I do now...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you reference it in your web.config

- under the controls tag (path: "< system.web>") :

  < add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting" assembly="System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
- under "< httphandlers>") :

  < add path="ChartImg.axd" verb="GET,HEAD"
  type="System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartHttpHandler,
  System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral,
  PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" validate="false"/>